# messageBox Title Field Value in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, content-editor-web-part

How can we get the Title value at editform.aspx load event and save the value to variable then alert the value as messageBox

Any help with java script please

Answer (score 0):

From the input elements, use the browser inspect (for chrome -- Inspector) element to get the input id attribute value.

Then you can just use this (note: you need jquery, if you are not using jquery please let me know):

```
var currentTitle = '';
$(function(){
  currentTitle = document.getElementById('Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-
  0177e6ddd247_$TextField').value;
  alert(currentTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can following snippet in Script Editor web part on your editform.aspx page. This is a tested snippet.

`document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="Title_"]')[0].value);
  }
};`